# webdriver (c#) - Assert text from a specific UL tagname

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to assert that specific UL tags within my webpage contain certain text.  I'm not sure how to get for example, the third UL tag within a class and then assert it's text.  Here is an example of the HTML code from my webpage:

```
<td class="def"><ul>
<li>1 -- test 1</li>
<li>2 -- test 2</li>
<li>3 -- test 3</li>
<li>4 -- test four</li>
</ul></td>
```

I'm taking a different (and likely naive) approach to get this working but it's not really ideal for me - and I'm only doing it this way because I'm not sure how to get it working the way I would like.  I'm asserting that the length of text from the outer html of the "def" class contains a specific count:

(from memory)

```
String Def = utility.driver.findelement(By.ClassName("def").GetAttribute.("outerHTML");
int Length = Def.Length;
Assert.IsTrue(Length.equals("36"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either directly find that element using an XPath selector that matches on text (example selector below, not tested):

```
//td[contains(@class, 'def')]//ul/li[text()='4 -- test four')]
```

(find me a `td` that contains a `class` of `def`, get the `ul` underneath it, and get the `li` underneath *that* which **also** has a `text` of `4 -- test four`)

You can also harness the power of LINQ in C# to do some leg work for you. The thing you are missing is finding child elements of a given element. This is done by chaining `.FindElement` commands:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("def")).FindElement(By.TagName("ul"));
```

The above would get the first `ul` element that is a direct child of the `td` element in your example. WebDriver will be able to figure out the child & parent relationships for you.

So to put this into your situation a bit better, here's how you would do it.

```
Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("def"));
```

Get the `table` we want.

```
Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("def")).FindElement(By.TagName("ul"));
```

Get the `ul` we want that's a direct child of that `table`.

```
Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("def")).FindElement(By.TagName("ul")).FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
```

Get the `li` elements of that `ul`. Note the `FindElements` (extra s!)

```
Driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("def")).FindElement(By.TagName("ul")).FindElements(By.TagName("li")).First(i => i.Text.Equals("4 -- test four"));
```

Since it's an `IList` that returns, LINQ can then take it and return the first one that has a `.Text` property equal to what you need.